# Main T-SQL WHERE function seems to be wrongly applied to a subquery

Tags: sql, t-sql

This query returns a set of dates from tblValue whose FieldValue is type nvarchar(4000)

```
SELECT t1.FieldValue FROM (SELECT FieldValue
FROM tblValue
WHERE FieldID = 4) t1
WHERE DateAdd(day, -90, t1.FieldValue) <= GETDATE()
```

This works, but instead of hard-coding the FieldID of 4, I'd like to get all FieldValues for those which have the type "Expiration".
This query returns 4.

```
SELECT FieldID FROM tblField WHERE FieldType = 'Expiration'
```

So, I expect this query's innermost subquery to return 4, and then to have the DateAdd applied only to those Expiration values which are yielded from t1 in the outermost subquery, which is what happens in the working first example.

```
SELECT t1.FieldValue FROM (SELECT FieldValue
FROM tblValue
WHERE FieldID = (SELECT FieldID FROM tblField WHERE FieldType = 'Expiration')) t1
WHERE DateAdd(day, -90, t1.FieldValue) <= GETDATE()
```

But I get the error

> "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

which to me suggests that the DateAdd is being applied to all values of tblValue, not only to those which are yielded by the subquery which returns t1. There is probably a technical reason for it, but it doesn't seem right to me. For some reason

```
WHERE FieldID = 4) t1
```

is not equivalent to

```
WHERE FieldID = (SELECT FieldID FROM tblField WHERE FieldType = 'Expiration')) t1
```

It just so happens that if I leave off the final WHERE clause of the erroring query I get the same set of dates as in the working query. So t1 should not be presenting any values which the DateAdd should have a problem with. But there it is. I'm puzzled as to why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of the particular execution plan that the optimizer produces.  Depending on how it chooses to combine the comparison and filtering operations of the various clauses, it can do either one or the other first.

In this case, it's trying to perform the date conversion and comparison before applying the FieldType filter.

It's a well-known issue but inherent to the behavior of the SQL optimizer -- this is a similar issue with a different datatype:  https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/333312/error-8114-converting-data-type-varchar-to-numeric

There are ways around this, but they are not always straightforward and usually require you to force specific order of execution.

The below works for me, although I understand that the CASE technique is not always 100% effective.  From [this fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/da7e1/3/0):

```
SELECT t1.FieldValue FROM (SELECT FieldValue
FROM tblValue
WHERE FieldID = (SELECT FieldID FROM tblField WHERE FieldType = 'Expiration')) t1
WHERE CASE WHEN ISDATE(t1.FieldValue) = 1 THEN DateAdd(day, -90, t1.FieldValue) ELSE '1/1/2900' END <= GETDATE()
```

Comment: Thanks, mwigdahl. "Closed as By Design." Classic.

Comment: Yes, thanks, mwigdahl, the CASE statement will work, but it's a shame to uglify the code to override a non-optimizing "optimization."

Comment: Agreed; I've had to do that several times in my own code and it's not fun.  Also doesn't help that it really depends on index and data topology; a query can run for months just fine and then blow up like a forgotten landmine when the optimizer shifts the plan on you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want this?

```
SELECT * FROM tblValue v
JOIN tblField f ON v.FieldID = f.FieldID
WHERE f.FieldType = 'Expiration' AND DateAdd(day, -90, v.FieldValue) <= GETDATE()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that results in the same error. I tried that originally, but even with "IsDate(v.FieldValue) = 1" it seems t-sql does not  short-circuit, so the GetDate was being evaluated even when "IsDate(v.FieldValue) = 1" was false.

Comment: obviously you have rows with FieldType = 'Expiration' and incorrect datetime formats

Comment: @BobHoeppner T-SQL (or rather, the execution planner) does way more than just short circuit. The thing is, it doesn't guarantee the order of execution, and it has many optimizations that pretty much explicitly disallow doing your query the way you expect it to happen. It might help to join on both `FieldID` and `FieldType` at the same time, and ensure there's an index that covers both of those indices, but it's going to be rather fragile anyway. SQL queries are *not* procedural - they do not happen in the order they're written. There's tricks around this - you can use a `case` for example.

Comment: Ultimately I'd like to have more than one field of type Expiration, such as LicenseExpiration, ContractExpiration, etc. and use "WHERE FieldID IN", but for now there is just one Expiration field.

Comment: All Value rows of type Expiration have correct data format; hence, the first query works. Thanks, Luaan, I wondered if an "optimization" might be behind this, although it's hardly an optimization to process every record in the table with GetDate when it only has to run it against the t1 subset. I realize the SQL may not be strictly procedural, but I do expect it to use logical set theory, and it's specific that GetDate should operate only on the t1 subset, not the whole table.

Answer (score 0):

To categorize this as wrongly applied is not fair
You don't get to control which rows TSQL will evaluate
With a hard 4 the optimizer did that first
Without a hard 4 the query optimizer had to be ready for anything and moved it to later
The query optimizer even considers a derived table fair game to optimize
If you just look at the query plan you can see the order

Try

```
SELECT * 
  FROM tblValue v
  JOIN tblField f 
    ON v.FieldID = f.FieldID
   AND f.FieldType = 'Expiration' 
   AND DateAdd(day, -90, v.FieldValue) <= GETDATE()
```

Comment: Blam, your example results in the same error. I would think that when I specifically apply a function to t1 it should reasonably apply only to the subset t1 and not to the entire contents of the underlying table. If this is indeed due to an optimization strategy it is a non-optimizing optimization in this case, and one which defies the relatively simple logic of the query.

Comment: You can call this wrong or defy all you want but that is how it works. One of the conditions is going to be applied before the other.  If you would have a date in a datatime  type this would all go away.